# Haskell: Accessing Elements of a Custom List Type

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I have a problem with accessing the elements of my custom type.

I have these declarations:

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

data Objekt = Objekt Suit Value
  deriving(Eq,Show)
data Suit = Hearts | Spades | Diamonds | Clubs
  deriving(Eq,Show)
data Value = Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
  deriving(Eq,Show)

data Deck = Deck [Objekt]
  deriving(Eq,Show)
```

Now, I'm creating a deck like so:

`let deck = Deck [Objekt Hearts Seven, Objekt Clubs Queen]`

and then I want to examine the deck:

`elem (Objekt Hearts Seven) deck`

and I get an error:

```
*Main> elem (Objekt Hearts Seven) deck

<interactive>:8:28: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Objekt]’ with actual type ‘Deck’
    • In the second argument of ‘elem’, namely ‘deck’
      In the expression: elem (Objekt Hearts Seven) deck
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = elem (Objekt Hearts Seven) deck
```

The Deck shows the following:

```
*Main> deck
Deck [Objekt Hearts Seven,Objekt Clubs Queen]
*Main> :t Deck
Deck :: [Objekt] -> Deck
```

No matter what I do (I tried using map or list comprehensions), I can't access the elements of the deck.
I googled all day but I can't seem to find any example of custom list type and its accessing.

Am I doing the declaration correctly?

How can I test or extract the elements of my deck?

Anyone have an idea?
Any help would be appreciated...
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Deck` is a type which is different from a list type, yet it contains precisely a list.

You can convert a list into a `Deck` with the value constructor:

```
Deck :: [Objekt] -> Deck
```

This is what you have used in e.g. `let deck = Deck [....]`.

You can convert a `Deck` back into a list with a small helper function which you can add to your file:

```
unDeck :: Deck -> [Objekt]
unDeck (Deck os) = os
```

After this, you can use `elem someObjekt (unDeck someDeck)`.

Another option is using pattern matching, as Nykros pointed out. If you are learning Haskell, I'd recommend you get used to pattern matching, since it's very idiomatic in Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the list of cards is inside the Deck constructor. You should use pattern matching to extract the list.

You can define:

```
inDeck :: Objekt -> Deck -> Bool
inDeck card (Deck cards) = card  `elem` cards
```

Then, you can ask:

```
inDeck (Objekt Hearts Seven) deck
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. So if I declare it like this, then elements` sees only the list and not the deck anymore?

Comment: When you write down `Deck = Deck [Objekt]` you are telling Haskell to create a **new** data type, whose elements are built using the `Deck:: [Object] -> Deck` constructor function. If you meant to use deck as a synonym for [Object], then you should use `type Deck = [Object]`. Take a look at [link](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses)